# $\sum (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $\sum (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n^2}$ is convergent or divergent?

My attempt is following:

Applying the root test, we get $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$. Then, since lim sup of this sequence is $0$, the sum is convergent.

Is it ok?

Comment: The method is correct, but the limsup is not $0$

Comment: Another approach is a follows:  Using the binomial theorem, we have 

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}&=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1n}\right)^{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}\\\\&\le \frac1{\frac12 n^2 (n^2-1)\left(\frac1{n}\right)^2}\\\\&=\frac2{n^2-1}\end{align}$$

whence we assert the series converges by appealing to the comparison test

Answer (score 1):

Notice the following limit exists and is less than one:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)^{n} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^{-n}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\\\\
& = e^{-1} < 1
\end{align*}

Hence the proposed series converges according to the root test.